# Interface between R and C libraries / BLAS / OS X

Tags: c, r, macos

I'm writing some C programs (I'm quite a beginner in C), that I compile and call from R. In order to be as efficient as possible, I try to use as much as possible functions from Lapack and BLAS (which contain highly optimised routine to perform basic operations).

I compile my .c codes thanks to, classically:

```
system ('R CMD SHLIB blablabla.c')
```

Here is the "preamble" of my average  .c code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <R_ext/blas.h>
#include <R_ext/Lapack.h>
```

Here is my "dummy" problem: I need to compute the "argmin of a real vector", i.e., the index of the minimal component of the vector (in practice, for huge vectors and a lot of times, so that I really like to use an optimised routine, and not a basic "for" loop). 
"Unfortunately", in "R_ext/blas.h", the function IDMIN does not appear ("R_ext/blas.h" only contains the function IDAMAX, that returns the index of the maximum absolute value component).

In R, such a task is easily achieved by "which.min()" (which is, I guess, based on an optimised code), so I guess that it should "somewhere" exists the C code (certainly based on a FORTRAN code) that achieves this task, and this is exactly what I need...

In other words: what library should I add to my ".c preamble" and what C function should I use to be able to use an "optimised which.min()" in my C code (that I compile and call from R) ?

Another question: On Mac OS X, how to add some C libraries to the existing C libraries of R (still, with the view to compile and use C from R, which is in my view very convenient) ?

Thanks.

Comment: There is probably something for this in Eigen or Armadillo. Since I would suggest using Rcpp anyway, you should check them out and use RcppEigen or RcppArmadillo.

Comment: Agreed. I'm 99% sure this is in RcppEigen already.

Comment: Yup and yup. With (Rcpp)Armadillo you get LAPACK for free (as it dispatches) whereas (Rcpp)Eigen has its own alternates.  You really should use the Rcpp* family as it makes your life easier---you can still write C inside if you prefer (though I'd consider that misguided :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions (I'm not sure to really understand, but this is another problem ;-) ). Actually, I do not have any problem with Lapack, my problem is that R_ext/blas.h does not contain the equivalent of, in R, which.min(.)...   So, how does R proceed ?